# How to prove $G':\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ varies continuously in $\mathbb{R^3}$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, functions, continuity

**Given:**

$G:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}=$ a continuous function of $r=G(r)$

$G':\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}=$ a radial field $=G(r)$

**To prove:**

$G':\mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ varies continuously in $\mathbb{R^3}$

*In short, we need to prove a radial field is continuous everywhere*

> My attempt:
>
> $G:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}=$ a continuous function of $r$
>
> In domain $\mathbb{R}$ containing origin of radial vector field, $G(r)$ is continuous everywhere.
>
> For $\epsilon_1>0$,
>
> $\exists\ \delta_1>0 \ni |r-r_0|<\delta_1 \implies|G(r)-G(r_0)|<\epsilon_1$
>
> In domain $\mathbb{R^3}$, $r$ is continuous everywhere.
>
> For $\delta_1>0$,
>
> $\exists\ B (\delta_2, r_0) \ni |(x,y,z)-(x_0,y_0,z_0)|<\delta_2 \implies|r-r_0|<\delta_1$

Now what shall I do? How shall I apply the composition rule?

Comment: it is a composition of two continuous functions

Comment: Yeah I know... but I can't get an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. Please show it in an answer.

Comment: what does it mean for two functions to be continuous? What are you supposed to prove to show their composition is continuous? You really just have to modify the standard proof that a composition of continuous functions is continuous, but if you don't post an attempt of what you've done I can't really help you

Comment: I am new to this and I am confused while writing the proof and don't seem to get any close to the answer. Can you provide an answer containing epsilon delta proof....